# Get portion of PHP variable

Tags: php

I need to get only a part of a PHP variable.

```
$somevar = "sd300.somedata.cd.vm.someotherdata.cd.vm";
```

Now, I cannot figure out, but I only need this first part and do away with the last part, then save the variable again as `$somevar`

I only need to capture `sd300.somdata.cd.vm`

I've tried `preg_replace` but just cannot figure it out.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: How do you determine what portion should be returned? Is it always the most center dot?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 2):

If you still wanted to use preg_replace:

```
$somevar = "sd300.somedata.cd.vm.someotherdata.cd.vm";
$somevar = preg_replace("/(.*\..*\..*\..*)\..*\..*\..*/", '$1', $somevar);
var_dump($somevar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `preg_match_all()` you can do this:

```
$somevar = "sd300.somedata.cd.vm.someotherdata.cd.vm";
$pattern = '/((.*?\.)(cd\.vm))/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $somevar, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => sd300.somedata.cd.vm
            [1] => .someotherdata.cd.vm
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => sd300.somedata.cd.vm
            [1] => .someotherdata.cd.vm
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => sd300.somedata.
            [1] => .someotherdata.
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => cd.vm
            [1] => cd.vm
        )

)
```

`$matches[0][0]` contains the [output you requested](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a39980e5517545129b01aa88dae9dd56928c3bec) in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this:

```
$somevar = "sd300.somedata.cd.vm.someotherdata.cd.vm";

$delimiter = '.cd.vm';

$temp = explode($delimiter, $somevar);
```

Your searched value:

```
$value = $temp[0] . $delimiter;
```

You didn't give a lot of information that is why I am guessing.

Answer (score 0):

The below logic would be helpful

```
$somevar = "sd300.somedata.cd.vm.someotherdata.cd.vm";
echo (implode('.',current(array_chunk(explode('.',$somevar),4))));
```